# How to convert one line of code from jquery to vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What to do with the line of code `$('#output').on('input ','.dynamic-Qty', function(e){`

```
$('#output').on('input ','.dynamic-Qty', function(e){
let z = e.target.dataset;
console.log(z.id)
console.log(this.value)

var itemInCart = false;
console.log(shopcart);
 let qtty = parseInt(this.value);
 if(qtty<0) {qtty = 0;this.value=0;}


shopcart.forEach((value, index) => {
    console.log(index + ' ' + value.id);
    if (value.id == z.id) {
        shopcart[index].qty= qtty;
        itemInCart = true;
    }
});

sessionStorage['shopcart'] = JSON.stringify(shopcart);
outputCart();
console.log(sessionStorage['shopcart']);

});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33015903/3037257

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla JS event listener should work:

```
document.getElementById("output").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    if (e.target.className == "dynamic-Qty") {
        //Rest of code
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh yes @ScottMarcus.

Comment: Nope. Error : The specified value "null" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: That's an issue with your code - mine is a transpilation of the line you wanted to turn into vanilla JS.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought that something was wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

It works)

```
document
    .querySelector('#output > .dynamic-Qty')
    .addEventListener("input", function(e){
        let z = e.target.dataset;
        console.log(z.id)
        console.log(this.value)

        var itemInCart = false;
        console.log(shopcart);
        let qtty = parseInt(this.value);
        if(qtty<0) {qtty = 0;this.value=0;}


        shopcart.forEach((value, index) => {
            console.log(index + ' ' + value.id);
            if (value.id == z.id) {
                shopcart[index].qty= qtty;
                itemInCart = true;
            }
        });

        sessionStorage['shopcart'] = JSON.stringify(shopcart);
        outputCart();
        console.log(sessionStorage['shopcart']);

    });
```